# Problem with repeat in writing algorithm with Latex

Tags: algorithms

I'm confused with my errors about using Repeat in algorithm, with other commands there is no problem but I cant use Repeat.
My code:

```
\begin{algorithm}
    \begin{LTR}
        \Repeat{$h=h+1$}{$h=5$}
    \end{LTR}
\end{algorithm}
```

my error is:

```
Missing \endcsname inserted. ^^I^^I\Repeat
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class and which algorithm-related LaTeX packages you employ.

Comment: Thanks, I 'm using documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran-fa}%12pt,journal, also it is not my main algorithm that you see in code I wanna write backtracking linesearch and I need Repeat...until, I 'm using algorithm package

Comment: Thanks. Is the `IEEEtran-fa` document class available online? I ask this question because it doesn't seem to be a part of the TeXLive distribution. Also, please don't tell us what you do *not* do; instead, do please provide information about which algorithm-related packages you actually load.

Comment: No I think It's not available online. Sorry, I'm using Algorithm and Algorithmic packages

Comment: And what about the `IEEEtran-fa` document class: Where might it be obtained from?

Comment: It's a template that my professor gives me for writing Persian papers in IEEE format, I'm not sure where it can be obtained.

Comment: Now I 'm trying wth (IEEEtran) but I have the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remark: I don't have access to the proprietary `IEEEtran-fa` document class files. (The string "fa" stands for "farsi", right?) However, I think that the OP's issue can be analyzed by (a) employing the `IEEEtran` document class and (b) omitting the `\begin{LTR}` and `\end{LTR}` directives.

The `algorithmic` package provides a directive named `\REPEAT` -- note the ALL-UPPERCASE lettering -- which, AFAICT, *must* be followed by `\STATE` and `\UNTIL` (again: all-uppercase) directives. For sure, the following code compiles fine.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional 
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}
  \REPEAT
  \STATE $h=h+1$
  \UNTIL $h=5$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, fa is for Farsi. Thanks a lot Mico, your instruction solved my problem.